calculate consecutive numeric values, but it fails because of floating point numbers jq command

With a Json field like the one below, if eventId is a continuous value,
I would like to add the value of the message field.
However, even if eventId is continuous, if the message field starts with # Time, the message field is separated.
This is the original field of Json.
{
    "events": [
        {
            "message": "# Time: 1",
            "eventId": "38636469249093328935961608873790523617989208925384015872"
        },
        {
            "message": ", 2, 3",
            "eventId": "38636469249093328935961608873790523617989208925384015873"
        },
        {
            "message": "# Time: 11",
            "eventId": "38636469249093328935961608873790523617989208925384015875"
        },
        {
            "message": "# Time: 12",
            "eventId": "38636469249093328935961608873790523617989208925384015876"
        },
        {
            "message": "# Time: A",
            "eventId": "1"
        },
        {
            "message": ", B, C",
            "eventId": "2"
        },
        {
            "message": "# Time: C",
            "eventId": "3"
        },
        {
            "message": "# Time: D",
            "eventId": "5"
        }
    ]
}


Here's what I want it to look like:
[
  {
    "message": "# Time: 1, 2, 3"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 11"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 12"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: A , B, C"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: C"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: D"
  }
]


I've asked a question about this before and received an answer from a great person. (Thank you pmf.)
After this, I tried my best to refine it a little more, but it didn't work, so I asked once more.
First,  When Ifirst run this JQ, I get the following results.
jq -r '.events 
| reduce .[1:][] as $i (.[:1];
    if ((.[-1].eventId | tonumber + 1 | tostring) != $i.eventId) or ($i.message | startswith("# Time:")) then
        . += [$i]
    else
        .[-1].message += " " + $i.message
    end
) 
| del(.[].eventId)
'

[
  {
    "message": "# Time: 1"
  },
  {
    "message": ", 2, 3"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 11"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 12"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: A , B, C"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: C"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: D"
  }
]


I saw it as a floating point issue and wanted to compare this number with the string itself, so I created a function as follows, but it did not work.
jq '
# Function to add one to a large number represented as a string
def add_one(num):
  (num | split("") | reverse | map(tonumber)) as $digits
  | reduce range(0; length) as $i ([];
      . + if $i == 0 or .[-1] == 10 then
            [($digits[$i] + 1) % 10]
         else
            [$digits[$i]]
         end
    )
  | reverse | map(tostring) | join("");

# Process events and check continuity
.events 
| map(.eventId |= tostring) # Ensure all eventIds are strings
| reduce .[1:][] as $i (.[:1];
    if (add_one(.[-1].eventId) != $i.eventId) or ($i.message | startswith("# Time:")) then
        . += [$i]
    else
        .[-1].message += " " + $i.message
    end
)
| del(.[].eventId)
'

[
  {
    "message": "# Time: 1"
  },
  {
    "message": ", 2, 3"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 11"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 12"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: A"
  },
  {
    "message": ", B, C"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: C"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: D"
  }
]


As I searched further, I found a command called gojq, but I would like to test it first to see if it is possible with jq.
I am using jq version 1.7.1.

If you can rely on the ordering of the items, and that only the right messages start with a #, you only have to check for occurrences of the latter.
reduce .events[] as {$message} ([];   # iterate over events, extract message
  if $message | startswith("#")       # if message starts with #
  then . + [{$message}]               # add a new item to the result list
  else last.message += $message end   # otherwise append it to last item's
)

Demo
However, implementing the stricter requirements is not much more difficult. Note that carrying over the eventId for comparison necessitates their removal afterwards.
def check($e1; $e2):
  ($e2.message[:1] != "#") and
  ($e1.eventId | tonumber) + 1 == ($e2.eventId | tonumber);

reduce .events[1:][] as $e (.events[:1];
  if check(last; $e) then last.message += $e.message else . + [$e] end
)
| map({message})  # drop eventId, just keep message

Demo
Output:
[
  {
    "message": "# Time: 1, 2, 3"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 11"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 12"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: A, B, C"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: C"
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: D"
  }
]


Thank you again this time. Following the answer you gave last time, I tried hard to think about using a function, but it didn't work out. (I can't get my head to work. lol)
From experience so far, eventId at least guarantees an order in which subsequent values ​​are larger.
I would really appreciate it if you could briefly explain the syntax. What I understood was that it just adds the message field and ends when # begins. Is this correct?

The second grammar you gave (def added) is expected to be much more stable because it checks more conditions. Thank you very much.

That was the goal. You're welcome. :)

Before posting a question, I tried various ways to solve the problem myself, but it didn't work.
I ended up posting my question again, and thank you so much for your response.
have a good day.
